# Python - Convert February 29 dates to date time objects

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert dates in string format to date time object but I keep getting a value error for 29th February dates. Here is my code.

```
from datetime import datetime

def try_parsing_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%Y-%m-%d', '%d.%m.%Y', '%m/%d/%Y', '%d/%m/%Y', '%d-%b-%y', '%d/%m/%y', '%m/%d/%y', '%m/%d/%Y'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError(text)

df['Dateofbirth'] = df.apply(lambda row: try_parsing_date(row['Dateofbirth']), axis=1)
```

The error I get is **ValueError: ('2/29/57', 'occurred at index 82445')**.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: There was no February 29, 1957. You have garbage input. You can catch the `ValueError` and adjust February 29 to either February 28 or March 1 for the given year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Python problem. 1957 wasn't a leap and 2/29/57 never existed. If someone claims that as his date of birth, he's lying. So you could as well put any date into your list - or nan.

Answer (score 0):

Error message I obtained was more specific and usefull:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('1957-02-29', '%Y-%m-%d')

ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

BTW there is a lot of misleading web sites about history informing 'what happend' on 29 Feb '57 :-)